# Google calculator giving weird result?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

So consider the following calculation

`5777100 - 5777090.001370444`

When I type it into Google, the result I get is

`9.99862955604`

and when I try using WolframAlpha I get

`9.998629556`

which is the same as my own calculation by hand.

What's going on here?

Comment: Google is not using real-number arithmetic. It is using some appproximations. Oddly, it does not appear to be using a standard IEEE-754 format. 2^48+1-2^48 produces 1, as in real-number arithmetic, but 2^49+1-2^49 produces 0. The IEEE-754 binary64 format would not fail until 2^53+1-2^53.

Comment: When you say Google is not using real-number arithmetic, you imply that WolframAlpha probably is using? Which means what? Maybe that they treat a very large number as a string of some sorts?

Comment: WolframAlpha includes some symbolic mathematics engine that can manipulate mathematical symbols similarly to the ways that humans do, including managing numbers as strings of digits at least up to some resource limits.